# How can I redirect a successful login to a specific URL in Spring MVC without using session attributes?

Tags: spring-mvc

I have been working on Spring MVC project and below are the point:
when customer comes to login page url is like : /login?target=/tnc
if customer enters incorrect login credentials url becomes: /login?error=true

I want even customer makes n number of incorrect attempt to login, whenever customer successfully logs in, customer should be redirected to /tnc.

I don't want to use session attribute explicitly. How can I achieve this?

Tried to redirect user to /login?target=/tnc&error=true but this is failing in security scan. So can't do this.